# GTK Memory leak while updating images

Tags: c, memory-leaks, gtk

I am using Gtk+3.0 to develop application in my embedded processor with C. In my apllication, I am having a manual mode screen, where i used to display 16 red/green color images based on the level of my input(HIGH/LOW). The problem is, when I try to update the images every 100ms, i could see that the ram memory is increasing and i think that there is memory leak while updating the gtk images. I have shared my code below. Any suggestions to avoid the memory leak are welcome.

```
void update_ui()
{
   for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
   {
       if(level==HIGH)  gtk_image_set_from_file(image[i],"path");
       else             gtk_image_set_from_file(image[i],"path1");
   }
}
```

while calling this function with g_timout_add() at an interval of 100ms, the images are changed well and good but the increase in ram memory is my problem. I tried with gtk_pixbuf_new also but the memory leak exists.

Thanks and regards

Comment: That's too small code portion.

Comment: This is the only function that  i am using to change the images at small intervals

Comment: Ok, then maybe it's not the place where memory leaks? How did you find it out?

Comment: Could you please teel me what `pkg-config --modversion gtk+-3.0` returns, to know the exact version of GTK+ you're using? I've spotted a possible memory leak on the GTK+ side, but would like to make some more checks.

Comment: @liberforce, i am using it a embedded processor so i cant find the exact version using this command. But i am using gtk+3.0 library only

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev, Actually this is only code i am having, so i am sure that only this is causing the memory leak.

Comment: @NaaiSekar You're not using GTK+ 3.0. GTK+ 3.0 was released in 2011. 3.0 here is the version af the ABI. Knowing exactly which version you're running would help to identify the source that matches that version. You may run `grep -E '#define GTK_(MAJOR|MINOR|MICRO)_VERSION' /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkversion.h` for that, or just paste here the values of `GTK_MAJOR_VERSION`, `GTK_MINOR_VERSION`, `GTK_MICRO_VERSION`.

Comment: If you still can't find it, just add a `g_print("GTK version: %d.%d.%d\n", GTK_MAJOR_VERSION, GTK_MINOR_VERSION, GTK_MICRO_VERSION);` at the beginning of your `update_ui` function.

Comment: @liberforce, Thanks mate. Now i found the verison of gtk. I am using GTK version 3.22.17

Comment: @liberforce, as you earlier mentioned that you have found a possible memory leak, is that due to gtk image?

Comment: That was when I first looked ate the code, I had the impression the filename was leaked, but after closer inspection it doesn't seem to be the case. Could you please write an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and possibly add the images you're using at `path` and `path1`? I'll test if I can reproduce the leak on GTK+ 3.22.30.